how to make a multiwindow electron app with react?
i am trying to make a child window in electron after the user clicks on a button rendered from react and this window communicates with the main electron proccess file to handle ipc communications
this is the child window
function childWindow(){
  const childWindowUp=new BrowserWindow({
    name:"child",
    width:700,
    height:700,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/childIndex.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })
  childWindowUp.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    shell.openExternal(details.url)
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })
  if (is.dev && process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL'])
  } else {
    childWindowUp.loadURL(` file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/demo/my-app/src/renderer/child.html`)
    
  }
  
  childWindowUp.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    childWindowUp.show()
  })
}

folder hierarchy
when i run the window nothing happened like here :
the window appear but the script is not executed
or it shows error for ipcRenderer:
window.Electron.ipcRenderer.send('child-message','hello from child js file')
console.log('the ipc message is sent to the srver')

this is the error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ipcRenderer')
    at child.html:33:17
Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
  Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
  this app to unnecessary security risks.

For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.
warnAboutInsecureCSP @ VM4 sandbox_bundle:2

